# ADFS url is machine name instead of FQDN

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008, adfs

I have a federation trust setup on a 2008 R2 server. The initial site is reached through the https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

but when you click the button you end up with

https://srvr2008.domain.local/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx

how can i change it from the computer name back to the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may well be a DNS or load balancer issue.

ADFS needs a federated service name and you can change it in the ADFS "Edit federation service properties" via the wizard.

Note that this should reflect to the SSL certificate name and the DNS.

Comment: it was the name in the federation services properties